# Using nodemon doesn't recognize Electron package

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nodemon

I'm trying to use the nodemon package in an Electron project but when I try to execute this with `nodemon main.js` I catch this error in terminal:

[image: Error when try to execute with nodemon]

[image: My package.json]

But when I try to execute simply with "npm electron ." this works properly. Why?

The code of `main.js`:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

createMainWindow = () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1600, height: 900,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('./renderer/index.html')

    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(createMainWindow);
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? Please post the relevant lines in `./main.js`.

Comment: Yes, I run it, I've tried to delete `node_modules` folder too, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved it. 
In package.json I changed the `"start": "nodemon ./main.js"` to "`watch": "nodemon --exec electron ."` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it by executing electron with npx:

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec npx electron ."
```

but this will run a new instance every time you make a change.

Alternatively, you can install electron globally:

```
npm i -g electron
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
As "Fabrício Pinto Ferreira" Said change package.json

```
"start": "nodemon ./main.js" to 
"watch": "nodemon --exec electron ."
```

and it was showing error of electron

Step 2:
I installed node globally

```
npm i -g electron
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in package.json add

"watch": "nodemon --exec electron ."

then run in terminal

nodemon --exec electron .

Comment: No need to provide answer if it is the same as the one already posted. Please like and comment on the answer you find correct.